# Jquery mobile append grid won't output properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

So here is my problem: I do a grid with 6 columns (5 being the max, I had to do a 3x2 grid).

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" id="currentgrid" style="height: 38px">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p></p>
```

The headers display properly, taking the width of the whole screen splitting the 6 headers equally. But here is the thing I don't understand. I try to `append()` the same part of code with a button with a js function but it doesn't output well. Here is the js line I use:

```
$("p").append('<div class=ui-grid-a" id="currentgrid" style="height: 38px"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">IP</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">TargetHardware</div></div><div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Position</div></div></div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Type</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">LiteralName</div></div><div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">ManufacturerCode</div></div></div></div></div>');
```

And then the output is all stretched to the left. The 6 columns now takes roughly 1/3 the width of the screen. Does anyone have clues about what could be the problem?

Comment: I would append it to #currentgrid or wrap <p></p> in a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile requires that you explicitly [create or refresh elements if they are dynamically created](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.html). Change the ID of the second grid (ID values must be unique) and add this line:

```
$('#secondgrid').grid('create');
```

Also see the working example below, which is also on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d23m5yv3/.

```js
$("p").append('<div class=ui-grid-a" id="secondgrid" style="height: 38px"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">IP</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">TargetHardware</div></div><div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Position</div></div></div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Type</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">LiteralName</div></div><div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">ManufacturerCode</div></div></div></div></div>');
$('#secondgrid').grid('create');
```

```html
<div class="ui-grid-a" id="currentgrid" style="height: 38px">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">Info6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p></p>
```

Comment: Didn't know about the id and now it actually display properly! Ty alot!